# windbg:Getting source code file at give address like "u address"

Tags: debugging, windbg

I have my windbg all set with srcpath and all.

I have added a breakpoint at one function and I can see the stack trace. When the breakpoint hits, the windbg shows the source code at current instruction with no problems. But I would like to see the source code at some other address. How can one see the sourcecode at given address like we can with disassembly We use "u "?

What command is for viewing source code? Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

.open -a  is your friend.  If you have yor symbols set up correctly, it will open the source that contains the code at the specified address.

Answer (score 1):

If You have the source code of debugging code why would You like to browse/view it from windbg? Source mode makes debugging very simple but windbg is not a "code browser".

If You want to see the source code at the given address simply check what function "covers" this address e.g.:

```
kd> uf fffff800`02be05d0
nt!NtOpenFile:
fffff800`02be05b0 4c8bdc          mov     r11,rsp
...
fffff800`02be05d0 458953e0        mov     dword ptr [r11-20h],r10d
```

Then ctrl-o and open your source code that contains this function(your func ofc unless You work for microsoft :D) and browse it in windbg.

Comment: Agreed :-) And further once you know the function in which the address falls, do a 'uf binary!functionname' this will display assembly code fore corresponding lines of source code with source file location

Comment: this is not so easy in case of lambda functions. Normally, you will see the callstack containing something like lambda_unnamed_3454564735().

Comment: AndreiM, if you know the name of your lambda, you can definitely find out where it is in source. Do a search in (private) symbols for your lambda name using x like so: "x [modulename]!`lambda<long string of hex>::operator()" and then do a u at that address. The latest version of windbg (10.0.10586.567) will do this for sure. It isn't 100% straight-forward, but at least it works.